# How to disable top page from dropdown menu wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I relly need help. I made a wordpress website, but i dont know how to disable top page from drom down menu.

I want to turn off page "Apartmani" because it is a empty page, so can you tell me how to disable that page and when you want to click on it nothing happens.
 Here s the picture http://www.dodaj.rs/f/t/13H/495kOjY8/pitanje.png so i want to unable "Apartmans".
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you do do this is not to add this "Apartmani" as a *Page* in your menu, but as a simple *link* (as you can add custom links in your menu), with "#" as target. As is you will have a menu item that will handle its sub-pages, but this item will not lead to anything at all as long as the targeted link is #...